# Writing typeclasses in C++

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, typeclass, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to write something similar in C++ to a set of typeclasses, and I'm struggling with how to arrange the template signatures, or if it's even possible to do what I want to do.

To break it down to its smallest example, say I have this:

```
template<typename S, typename T>
struct Homomorphism {
    //Defined in specialization: static const T morph(const S&);
    static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
    using src  = S;
    using dest = T;
};

template<typename S, typename T>
struct Monomorphism : Homomorphism<S, T> {
    //Defined in specialization: static const T morph(const &S);
    static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
    using src  = S;
    using dest = T;
};
```

I have specializations of these classes (and other morphisms) for data types in my program.

What I'd like to do now is to write a struct template that will take two homomorphisms or two monomorphisms and compose them to generate a new homomorphism or monomorphism struct respectively, i.e. something like:

```
template<typename S, typename T, typename U,
         typename HST = Homomorphism<S, T>,
         typename HTU = Homomorphism<T, U>,
         typename HSU = Homomorphism<S, U> >
struct CompositionMorphism : HSU {
    static const U morph(const S &s) {
        return HTU::morph(HST::morph(s));
    }
    static constexpr bool is_instance = true;
    using src  = S;
    using dest = U;
}
```

This actually worked for composing specialized instances of Homomorphism via:

```
CompositionMorphism<Class1, Class2, Class3>::morph(class1Instance);
```

when I had:

```
struct Homomorphism<Class1, Class2> {
    static const Class2 morph(const Class1 &c) {
        ...
    }
};
```

and analogous for `Homomorphism<Class2, Class3>`.

Now, however, I'd like to write:

```
template<typename S, typename T, typename U,
        typename MST = Monomorphism<S, T>,
        typename MTU = Monomorphism<T, U>,
        typename MSU = Monomorphism<S, U> >
struct CompositionMorphism : MSU {
    static const U morph(const S &s) {
        return MTU::morph(MST::morph(s));
    }
    static constexpr bool is_instance = true;
    using src  = S;
    using dest = U;
};
```

but the compiler is, unsurprisingly complaining about a duplicate definition of `CompositionMorphism`.

Is there a way to write `CompositionMorphism` and its specializations with `Homomorphism` and `Monomorphism` so that I will be able to do things like call:

```
template<> struct Homomorphism<Class1, Class2> { ... };
template<> struct Homomorphism<Class2, Class3> { ... };
CompositionMorphism<Class1, Class2, Class3>::morph(c1Instance);
```

or:

```
template<> struct Monomorphism<Class1, Class2> { ... };
template<> struct Monomorphism<Class2, Class3> { ... };
CompositionMorphism<Class1, Class2, Class3>::morph(c1Instance);
```

or:

```
template<> struct Monomorphism<Class1, Class2> { ... };
template<> struct Homomorphism<Class2, Class3> { ... };
CompositionMorphism<Class1, Class2, Class3>::morph(c1Instance);
```

and have the compiler pick the closest `CompositionMorphism` specialization based on my morphism hierarchy?

Comment: `CompositionMorphism(Class1, Class2, Classe)` — did you mean `Class3` and angle brackets here instead?

Comment: I'm not actually getting, when either of the classes should be chosen. (under which condition)

Comment: How will `CompositionMorphism` know if it's supposed to use a `Homomorphism` or `Monomorphism`? You need to disambiguate this and then all is well. You can't rely on previous explicit instatiations to make this selection since `CompositionMorphism` could instatiate a new version of both `Homo` and `Mono`.

Comment: @yeputons Yes, that's right. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll fix that.

Comment: @super The trick I'd ultimately like to achieve is to be able to have specializations for the special cases (i.e. the combinations of morphisms that yield more specialized forms of morphisms than vanilla homomorphisms, such as combining two monomorphisms), and have them default to the "base" template that composes homomorphisms if they don't conform to one of the special combinations.

Comment: I haven't done a lot of template programming in C++, though, so with regards to this, I'm not even sure it is possible. If it's not, and someone has a better recommendation how to organize this, that would be sincerely appreciated as well.

Comment: @Sebastian This can be done. You could for example SFINAE all possible combinations of `Homo/Mono<Class1, Class2>` combinations and see if they have a `morph` function. That will however lead to problems if there are more then 1 combination possible. The easiest approach would be to simply pass the specializations directly, like `CompositionMorphism<Homo<C1, C2>, Mono<C2, C3>, Homo<C1, C3>>`.

Comment: @super This is all new to me, and this personal project is to play some C++ catchup since I used to do a lot of non-template programming in it pre C++11. I hadn't hear of SFINAE before, but yes, I think that is the correct assumption since there will definitely be combinations that do not exist. For any data types where there are morphisms `C1,C2` and `C2,C3`, there is a preferred composition: `Homo,Homo` composition is the weakest form as it offers the least guarantees about the nature of the morphism. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like writing a template to select `Homomorphism` or `Monomorphism` based on SFINAE on the `morph` function.

```
template <typename S, typename T, typename = void>
struct SelectMorphism {
    using type = Homomorphism<S, T>;
};

template <typename S, typename T>
struct SelectMorphism<S, T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(Monomorphism<S, T>::morph(std::declval<S>())), const T>>> {
    using type = Monomorphism<S, T>;
};
```

This will check if `Monomorphism<S, T>::morph(S)` would return a `T`, if so select a `Monomorphism<S, T>`. If not SFINAE will fail and default to a `Homomorphism<S, T>`.

Then we change `CompositionMorphism` to use this template like so

```
template<typename S, typename T, typename U,
         typename HST = typename SelectMorphism<S, T>::type,
         typename HTU = typename SelectMorphism<T, U>::type,
         typename HSU = typename SelectMorphism<S, U>::type >
struct CompositionMorphism : HSU {
    static const U morph(const S &s) {
        return HTU::morph(HST::morph(s));
    }
    static constexpr bool is_instance = true;
    using src  = S;
    using dest = U;
};
```

You can see a [live demo here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vLusQnwVgN5TxUO4) of this full working example. It requires `c++17` but can be written for `c++11` as well (slightly more verbose).

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename S, typename T>
struct Homomorphism {
    //Defined in specialization: static const T morph(const S&);
    static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
    using src  = S;
    using dest = T;
};

template<typename S, typename T>
struct Monomorphism : Homomorphism<S, T> {
    //Defined in specialization: static const T morph(const &S);
    static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
    using src  = S;
    using dest = T;
};

template <typename S, typename T, typename = void>
struct SelectMorphism {
    using type = Homomorphism<S, T>;
};

template <typename S, typename T>
struct SelectMorphism<S, T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(Monomorphism<S, T>::morph(std::declval<S>())), const T>>> {
    using type = Monomorphism<S, T>;
};

struct Class1 {};

struct Class2 {};

struct Class3 {};

template<>
struct Monomorphism<Class1, Class2> : Homomorphism<Class1, Class2> {
    static const Class2 morph(const Class1&) { std::cout << "Morphing in Mono<Class1, Class2>" << std::endl; return Class2{}; }
    static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
    using src  = Class1;
    using dest = Class2;
};

template<>
struct Homomorphism<Class2, Class3> {
    static const Class3 morph(const Class2&) { std::cout << "Morphing in Homo<Class2, Class3>" << std::endl; return Class3{}; }
    static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
    using src  = Class2;
    using dest = Class3;
};

template<typename S, typename T, typename U,
         typename HST = typename SelectMorphism<S, T>::type,
         typename HTU = typename SelectMorphism<T, U>::type,
         typename HSU = typename SelectMorphism<S, U>::type >
struct CompositionMorphism : HSU {
    static const U morph(const S &s) {
        return HTU::morph(HST::morph(s));
    }
    static constexpr bool is_instance = true;
    using src  = S;
    using dest = U;
};

int main ()
{
    CompositionMorphism<Class1, Class2, Class3>::morph(Class1{});
}
```

Comment: This is great (and at this point, very over my head, so I'll be looking through STL pages tonight), but I still have a couple of questions. First off, what is the type of HSU in the example? I can't tell, but I'd like to be able to make inferences about the morphism that results from the composition. Second, how would this work if I threw two more morphisms in the mix: say an Epimorphism<S,T> which subclasses Homomorphism, and say Isomorphism, which subclasses both Epimorphism<S,T> and Monomorphism<S,T>? Is that even possible to capture?

Comment: Oh, and C++17 is ideal, since I'm trying to explore as many C++17 developments as possible.

Comment: @Sebastian HSU in this example is `Homomorphism<Class1, Class3>`. Since there is no specialization for `Mono<C1, C3>` it defaults to `Homo`. There is however no specialization for `Homo` either so the un-specialized version of `Homomorphism` is instatiated. It has no `morph` function but it still works since `morph` is never called on that class.

Comment: @Sebastian This example could absolutely be extended to include more morphisms. If there is a simple rule to follow for which one should be chosen or in which order they should be chosen it would probably be ok to extend this. If the rules for which type get selected is more complex this kind of automatically selecting templates would probably get quite messy and hard to write/maintain/debug.

Answer (score 1):

OK, Sometimes i need a little more thinking, but this is probably what you are looking for:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>

template<typename S, typename T>
struct Homomorphism;

template<typename S, typename T>
struct Monomorphism;

class Class1{};
class Class2{};
class Class3{};

template<> struct Homomorphism<Class1, Class2> 
{ 
     static const Class2 morph(const Class1&); 
     static constexpr bool is_instance = true;#
};

template<> struct Homomorphism<Class2, Class3> 
{
    static const Class3 morph(const Class2&);
    static constexpr bool is_instance = true;
};

template<typename S, typename T>
struct Homomorphism {
    //Defined in specialization: static const T morph(const S&);
    static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
    using src  = S;
    using dest = T;
};

template<typename S, typename T>
struct Monomorphism : Homomorphism<S, T> {
    //Defined in specialization: static const T morph(const &S);
    static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
    using src  = S;
    using dest = T;
};


namespace details {
    template<typename T, typename U, std::enable_if_t<Homomorphism<T,U>::is_instance>* = nullptr>
    U morph (const T& t)
    {return  Homomorphism<T,U>::morph(t);}

    template<typename T, typename U,  std::enable_if_t<Monomorphism<T,U>::is_instance>* = nullptr>
    U morph (const T& t)
    {return  Monomorphism<T,U>::morph(t);}


 }

template <typename S, typename T, typename U>
class CompositionMorphism
{
public:
    static U morph (const S& s)  {return  details::morph<T,U>(details::morph<S,T>(s));}
    static constexpr bool is_instance = true;
};


 int main(int, char**)
{
    Class1 c1Instance;
    CompositionMorphism<Class1, Class2, Class3>::morph(c1Instance);
    std::ignore = d;
}
```

And you might possibly want to create composed Homo/Mono morphism manually as follows:

```
template <> class Monomorphism<Class1,Class3> : public CompositionMorphism<Class1, Class2, Class3> {};
```

Then they can be reused by CompositionMorphism automatically.

Comment: I think this is going to get me where I want to be, since it allows me to mix different morphism types arbitrarily.

Comment: I have a further question with regards to the last line in creating composes Homo/Mono morphisms manually (which is what I do want to do.

Comment: Basically, I have a lookup table that, based on pairs of morphism types, can determine the type of the composition morphism. For example, a monomorphism composed with an epimorphism is a homomorphism, but a monomorphism composed with an automorphism is a monomorphism. Is there any way to encode this and use this type information in the manually created example in your last line?

Comment: If is wasn't clear, instead of template <> class Monomorphism<Class1, Class2>, is there any way to do a lookup on the morphism type of <Class1,Class2> and <Class2,Class3> and use that to assign the type instead of needing to know, as a user, that this is a Monomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

As observed by Super, if you pass only `T`, `U` and `V` the compiler doesn't know if is the case to chose `Homomorphism` or `Monomorphism`.

So I suppose you should pass `Homomorphism<T, U>` and `Homomorphism<U, V>` (`Homomorphism<T, V>` can be constructed) or `Monomorphism<T, U>` and `Monomorphism<U, V>`

If you want impose two `Homomorphism` **or** two `Monomorphism` (I mean: if you want exclude a `Monomorphism` toghether with a `Homomorphism`) you can write something as follows

```
template <typename, typename>
struct CompositionMorphism;

template <template <typename, typename> class C,
          typename S, typename T, typename U>
struct CompositionMorphism<C<S, T>, C<T, U>>
 {
   using comp = C<S, U>;

   static const U morph (const S & s)
    { return C<T, U>::morph(C<S, T>::morph(s)); }
 };
```

and call it as follows

```
   Homomorphism<int, long>        h0;
   Homomorphism<long, long long>  h1;
   Monomorphism<int, long>        m0;
   Monomorphism<long, long long>  m1;

   CompositionMorphism<decltype(h0), decltype(h1)>  h2;
   CompositionMorphism<decltype(m0), decltype(m1)>  m2;

   // compiler error
   //CompositionMorphism<decltype(h0), decltype(m1)>  hm;
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename S, typename T>
struct Homomorphism
 {
   //Defined in specialization: static const T morph(const S&);
   static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
   using src  = S;
   using dest = T;
 };

template <typename S, typename T>
struct Monomorphism : Homomorphism<S, T>
 {
   //Defined in specialization: static const T morph(const &S);
   static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
   using src  = S;
   using dest = T;
 };

template <typename, typename>
struct CompositionMorphism;

template <template <typename, typename> class C,
          typename S, typename T, typename U>
struct CompositionMorphism<C<S, T>, C<T, U>>
 {
   using comp = C<S, U>;

   static const U morph (const S & s)
    { return C<T, U>::morph(C<S, T>::morph(s)); }
 };


int main ()
 { 
   Homomorphism<int, long>        h0;
   Homomorphism<long, long long>  h1;
   Monomorphism<int, long>        m0;
   Monomorphism<long, long long>  m1;

   CompositionMorphism<decltype(h0), decltype(h1)>  h2;
   CompositionMorphism<decltype(m0), decltype(m1)>  m2;

   // compiler error
   //CompositionMorphism<decltype(h0), decltype(m1)>  hm;

   static_assert( std::is_same<Homomorphism<int, long long>,
                               decltype(h2)::comp>{}, "!" );

   static_assert( std::is_same<Monomorphism<int, long long>,
                               decltype(m2)::comp>{}, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: Actually, I want to be able to include every morphism type (and there are six, and some with multiple inheritance) with every other morphism type: however, there are only six special cases, and for everything else, I'd like it to be able to default back to the closest case with regards to parent class of the morphisms. (Homo / homo is the most generic.)

I'll take a look at all this shortly. Thanks!

Comment: And a function a la `make_xx` might help: `template <typename M1, typename M2> CompositionMorphism<M1, M2> ComposeMorphism(const M1&, const M2&) { return {}; }` and then `auto h2 = ComposeMorphism(h0, h1);`.

Comment: And, in fact I think that OP just wants different overloads of `ComposeMorphism`.

Comment: This is it exactly. I want to be able to overload `ComposeMorphism` with different types of morphisms as parameters, but I can't seem to get that to happen.